# Unable to establish connection to mosquitto broker from Arduino+ESP8266

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto, broker

I am using Arduino Uno and ESP8266 for WIFI connectivity. My Laptop on which mosquitto broker is running and Arduino(through ESP8266) is are both connected to wifi network. But I am unable to establish a connection to mqtt server.

I am using the follwing code.

```
    #define FASTLED_INTERNAL
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include <DHT.h>
    #include <WiFiEsp.h>
    #include <WiFiEspClient.h>
    #include <WiFiEspUdp.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h>
    #include <FastLED.h>
    
    #define DHTPIN 2
    #define DHTTYPE DHT11
    #define ESP_RX 9
    #define ESP_TX 8
    #define WIFI_AP "Anurag"
    #define WIFI_PASSWORD "qwerty12345"
    #define NUM_LED 64
    #define DATA_PIN 5
    #define CLOCK_PIN 13
    
    static const int RXPin = 4, TXPin = 3;
    static const uint32_t baudRate = 9600;
    static const int rainSensorMin = 0;
    static const int rainSensorMax = 1024;
    
    
    WiFiEspClient espClient;
    PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient);
    IPAddress broker(192,168,43,235);
    
    SoftwareSerial ESP8266(ESP_RX, ESP_TX);
    DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
    
    int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
    char *ID = "uno";
    char *TOPIC = "weatherStats";
    
    int AT_cmd_time;
    boolean AT_cmd_result = false;
    CRGB leds[NUM_LED];
    
    void setup() {
      //pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
      //FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN>(leds, NUM_LED);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      //ss.begin(baudRate);
      initWiFi();
      dht.begin();
      mqttClient.setServer(broker,1883);
      Serial.println("GPS, DHT11, and, Raindrop detector started.");
    }
    
    void loop() {
    
      status = WiFi.status();
      if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
          Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
          Serial.println(WIFI_AP);
          // Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
          status = WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
          delay(500);
        }
        Serial.println("Connected to AP");
      }
      
      delay(3000);
      float h = dht.readHumidity();
      float t = dht.readTemperature();
      int rainReading = analogRead(A0);
      int range = map(rainReading, rainSensorMin, rainSensorMax, 0, 2);
      if(!mqttClient.connected()){
        reconnect_mqtt();
      }
      mqttClient.loop();
      mqttClient.publish(TOPIC,"one step forward");
      //Serial.println("Satellites: " + String(gps.satellites.value()));
      if (!isnan(h) || !isnan(t))
        Serial.print("Temparture: " + String(t) + "°C | " + " Humidity: " + String(h) + " | ");
      else {
        Serial.println("Failed to obtain temparature and humidity data");
      }
      switch (range) {
        case 0:
          Serial.print("Rain Warning : 1");
          break;
        case 1:
          Serial.print("Rain Warning : 0");
          break;
      }
      Serial.println(" | Lat: 22.716191217468406 Lon: 72.44229199663788");
    }
    
      
    
    void initWiFi(){
      ESP8266.begin(9600);
      WiFi.init(&ESP8266);
      // check for the presence of the shield
      if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SHIELD) {
        Serial.println("WiFi shield not present");
        // don't continue
        while (true) {
          
        }
      }
    
      // attempt to connect to WiFi network
      while ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
        Serial.println(WIFI_AP);
        //Connect to WPA/WPA2 network
        status = WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
      }
    }
    
    void reconnect_mqtt(){
      while(!mqttClient.connected()){
        Serial.println("Attempting MQTT Connection");
        if(mqttClient.connect(ID)){
          Serial.println("MQTT connection established.");
          Serial.print("Publishing to: ");
          Serial.println(TOPIC);
        }
        else{
          Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
          delay(5000);
        }
      }
    }
```

Runnig this code I keep getting output "try again in 5 seconds". Please help.

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you using and how have you configured it?

Comment: And can you connect to it using the same credentials and `mosquito_pub` from a computer other than the one the broker is running on?

Comment: Actually the real problem was caused by firewall. I tried turning of windows firewall and it and the client connected to broker immediately. Thanks for response.